# Python: scheduling a script to run at particular time, need help in deciding which option is best

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduling, win32com, apscheduler

I have around 50 scripts that i want to run at different time of the day and display its result in CSV as well as web interface. For reason i cannot use flask-apscheduler. I do want an option to start the script or send scheduled time via cmd line. I have following options.

1. To use flask with APScheduler module
2. Use window scheduler in win32com.client module
3. use Sched module
4. is sched same as schedule ?

-- My machine is windows.
-- Python 3.8.6
-- I do not have options to pip install or conda install packages outside my network( so flask-apscheduler would not work )

My code needs to be run once per day, it just goes through database and needs to extract most current data that i will be displaying it on my web interface. Since the script are in python I would like it be using python for scheduling as well.

Comment: Do you want it to run once a day? or for a couple of days? Please explain how and when you want your code to ran. ALso how  the code looks like? is it classes? function? raw code?, what is the code about?
Please add more details.

Comment: Does your scheduling logic need to be defined in Python?  If not, you can just use [cron (Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) or [Task Scheduler (Windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) to run your scripts at the scheduled times.

Comment: updated my post for these comment @David